# Dissolved Oxygen Meter

Tags: oxygen

[image: 21.1]
[image: tip]

I have an Extech Heavy Duty Dissolved Oxygen Meter (Model 407510). Tech support for this company is terrible, so I'm asking questions here.

The manual says to expect a reading of 20.9 for calibrating to ambient air.
I'm getting 21.1. Is this acceptable variation? I am at 2133m/7000 ft ASL.

What is the clear membrane (if that's the right word) end of a DO meter made of?
Presumably it is some sort of gas-permeable polymer (?).

[Photos here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBCsH.jpg)

Comment: That is not an unusual reading for an oxygen monitor at 5500 ft ASL in a well ventilated place. What is the quoted calibration?

Comment: The manual says to expect a reading of 20.9 for calibrating to ambient air. And yes, 0.2 doesn't sound too far off, but then again 19.5, a difference of 1.4, is not considered safe. Just asking.

Comment: Listed accuracy is +/-0.7% so seems OK. Are you intending to use that in life safety applications? (“Safe” is a imprecise word, if you don’t understand impacts of oxygen deficient environments please talk to somebody who does.)

Comment: Not an oxygen deficient environment in the sense of someone entering an enclosed space, but thanks for pointing that out.